# Export multi page pdf with gimp

Tags: gimp, python

I understand that it may be possible using imageMagicks:

`convert image.mng out.pdf`

however is there a gimp way of doing this?

I also saw this script/plugin which uses `convert`:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzdkgv2f0jrbw6i/export-layers-to-pdf.py?dl=0

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Author: helour
# Copyright: 2013-2015 helour
# Based on the cr33dog's script Export Layers as PNG (http://registry.gimp.org/node/18440)
# License: GPL v3+
#
# Version: 0.7
#
# GIMP plugin to export layers as a multiple pages PDF file
#
#
# Note for Windows users:
#
# You need add the ImageMagic directory (which consists the 'convert.exe' executable file)
# to the GIMP environment PATH variable into the file:
# C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\lib\gimp\2.0\environ\default.env
#
# like in the example here:
# PATH=${gimp_installation_dir}\bin;${gimp_installation_dir}\32\bin;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16
# PYTHONPATH=${gimp_installation_dir}\32\lib\gimp\2.0\python
 
 
import os
import gtk
from subprocess import check_call
from tempfile import mkstemp
 
from gimpfu import *
 
def mktmpfile(suffix):
        fd, filename = mkstemp(suffix=suffix)
        fptr = os.fdopen(fd)
        return filename
 
def get_layers_to_export(layers, only_visible, gimp_version):
        result = []
        for layer in layers:
                if gimp_version >= 2.8 and pdb.gimp_item_is_group(layer):
                        result += get_layers_to_export(layer.children, only_visible, gimp_version)
                else:
                        if only_visible:
                                if layer.visible:
                                        result.append(layer)
                        else:
                                result.append(layer)
        return result
 
def combine_images_into_pdf(img_files, pdf_file):
        try:    # Run on shell because of conflict with windows system command 'convert.exe'
                check_call(['convert'] + img_files + [pdf_file], shell = True if os.name == 'nt' else False)
        except Exception as e:
                pdb.gimp_message("Error while executing 'convert' command:\n" +
                                 str(e) +
                                 "\n\nHave you installed the ImageMagic package\nand/or\nset the GIMP environment PATH variable?")
 
def export_layers(image, only_visible, quality):
        if not image.filename:
                pdb.gimp_message("Please save your file first!")
                return
 
        chooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title = None, action = gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE,
                                        buttons = (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL, gtk.STOCK_OPEN, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        chooser.set_current_folder(os.path.dirname(image.filename))
        chooser.set_current_name(os.path.splitext(image.filename)[0] + '.pdf')
        if chooser.run() != gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
                return
        filename = chooser.get_filename()
        chooser.destroy()
 
        version = gimp.version[0:2]
        gimp_version = float(version[0]) + float(version[1]) / 10.0
 
        layers_to_export = get_layers_to_export(image.layers, only_visible, gimp_version)
        img_files = []
        try:
                for layer in layers_to_export:
                        ext = '.jpg' if quality < 100 else '.png'
                        fullpath = mktmpfile(ext)
                        img_files.append(fullpath)
                        pic_filename = os.path.basename(fullpath)
                        if quality < 100:
                            pdb.file_jpeg_save(image, layer, fullpath, pic_filename, quality / 100.0, 0, 1, 0, "", 0, 1, 0, 2)
                        else:
                            pdb.file_png_save(image, layer, fullpath, pic_filename, 0, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                combine_images_into_pdf(img_files, filename)
        finally:
                for img in img_files:
                        try:
                                os.remove(img)
                        except:
                                pass
 
register(
        "export-layers-to-pdf", #name
        "Export layers to a multiple pages PDF file", #description
        "Export all layers to a single multiple pages PDF file", #help
        "helour", #author
        "helour", #copyright
        "2015", #year
        "Export layers to PDF", #menu label
        "*", # image format
        [       #input args. Format (type, name, description, default [, extra])
                (PF_IMAGE, "image", "Image", None),
                (PF_BOOL, "only_visible", "Only Visible Layers?", True),
                (PF_SLIDER, "quality", "Image quality", 100, (10, 100, 1)),
        ],
        [], #results. Format (type, name, description)
        export_layers, #callback
        menu=("<Image>/File/Export/"),
)
 
main()
```

However, I am not seeing a `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/share/gimp/2.0/plug-ins` folder, so i made one and put the python script inside of it as well as ran `chmod +x` on the script.

I also saw something in the python-fu browser, but have no idea how to use it:

[image]

"images" is undefined:

[image]

Gimp 2.8.14 Mac osx

I also followed some advice to look in `/Library` but didn't find anything:

```
➜  /Library  sudo find . | grep -i gimp
Password:
./Caches/Homebrew/brew-cask--git/Casks/gimp.rb
./Caches/Homebrew/brew-cask--git/Casks/lisanet-gimp.rb
./Caches/Homebrew/Formula/gimp.brewing
```

Is there anyway to easily install plugins that I am missing here?

## update

With the help of @tmanni in irc i was able to find the script path `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins` inside preferences > plug-ins:

[image]

However, the plugin would exit saying `convert` is not installed.

I then tried to add `/usr/local/bin` to the Plug-Ins path in the menu but it then crashes with an exit code status of -5.

I then tried to directly `ln -s /usr/local/bin/convert /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/bin/convert` but no dice there either.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use an application more suited for working with multiple pages?

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick? Also, have you read this? https://patrick-nagel.net/blog/archives/199/comment-page-1

Comment: @AAGD The first two lines of my question addresses what has been discussed in the blog post. I have installed ImageMagick via `brew` as in: `which convert`  outputs `/usr/local/bin/convert`

Comment: @jm_____ So using the command line ImageMagick will convert your .mng but not via your Python Plugin script? Have you tried that first?

Comment: @AAGD I didn't use mng i instead opted to use jpgs. That was the method that I used to get the pdf out on time. I installed a different plugin that exported each layer as an image, renamed the layers in consecutive numerical order and ran a `convert *.jpg out.pdf`, but the question still stands. I have been messing around with the script and been trying to debug why it isn't working correctly on mac.

Comment: @jm_____ What actually should happen is that you get an "Export layers to PDF" option in the File Menu. You can see it in action here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPv_wu-7pho&feature=youtu.be  Seems like the plugin isn't intended for Macs.

Comment: @jm_____ Here's another option without Gimp using Automator: https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/a-plugin-to-export-layers-in-gimp-file-to-single-pdf-file/comment-page-1/#comment-7883

Comment: @AAGD thanks for the suggestions. I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

After spending the better part of a week fiddling around with this:

```
➜  gimp_export_layers_to_pdf git:(master) brew --config
    HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
    ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
    HEAD: b51d0bc7f7b3575227538f84151b3fa4318f2774
    Last commit: 42 minutes ago
    HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
    HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
    HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
    HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
    CPU: 8-core 64-bit haswell
    OS X: 10.10.5-x86_64
    Xcode: 7.1.1
    CLT: 7.1.0.0.1.1444952191
    Clang: 7.0 build 700
    X11: N/A
    System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
    Perl: /usr/bin/perl
    Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
    Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    Java: 1.6.0_65-b14-468
```

## Solution:

I opened a git repo for this script, I was a bit surprised about how difficult the plugin registry for gimp was, however I got it to a point where it will work if **the pdf is exported with a quality less than 100**:

- https://github.com/jmunsch/gimp_export_layers_to_pdf

## The longer story:

Basically what was happening was gimp was using the default libraries that are included with gimp (sounds like a good idea) until I open gimp from terminal:

```
➜  ~  /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP ~/Desktop/Export_These_Layers.xcf
...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 19.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 18.0.0
```

convert is installed?:

```
➜  ~  ls -la /usr/local/bin/convert
    lrwxr-xr-x  1 jmunsch  admin  41 Nov 26 15:47 /usr/local/bin/convert -> ../Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/bin/convert
```

what libraries is convert using

```
➜  ~  otool -L /usr/local/bin/convert
    /usr/local/bin/convert:
        /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
        /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 19.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
        /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.2.0)
        /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
        /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
        /usr/local/opt/libtool/lib/libltdl.7.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

Everything appears to be up to date?

So how many places is that library?:

```
➜  ~ locate libfreetype
    /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
    /Applications/Steam.app/Contents/MacOS/libfreetype.dylib
    /Volumes/Gimp 2.8.14/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
    /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
    /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
    /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/lib/libfreetype.a
    /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/lib/libfreetype.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.a
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib
```

Oh, I see:

```
➜ ~ otool -L /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
    /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib:
        /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 19.0.0, current version 18.0.0)
```

So I copy it over:

```
➜  ~  cp /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib
```

And Retry:

```
➜  ~  /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP ~/Desktop/Export_These_Layers.xcf
Setting up environment...
Enabling internal Python...
Launching GIMP...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libfreetype.6.dylib requires version 34.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 29.0.0
[1]    69814 trace trap  /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP ~/Desktop/Export_These_Layers.xcf
```

so I try libpng and copy it over to gimp:

```
➜  ~  locate libpng16 
.
.
.
➜  ~  cp /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.18/lib/libpng16.16.dylib /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib
```

Restart the gimp from terminal and retry using the plugin:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
  Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 8.0.0 or later, but liblzma.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

okay where is it pulling this library from:

```
➜  ~  otool -L /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib:
    /usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.2.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)

➜  ~  otool -L /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
liblzma.5.dylib:
    /Users/gimpdev/gimp/10.6/inst/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
```

And so I copy that file over as well:

```
cp /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib
```

Yet another issue after linking the new libraries:

```
convert: unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
convert: unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

I retry but build from source this time:

```
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

Retry and same issue with PNG module, So I run `brew doctor`:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

So I retry installing `libpng`:

```
➜  ~   brew uninstall imagemagick; brew install imagemagick;brew install libpng; brew link libpng
    Warning: libpng-1.6.19 already installed
    Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.19
    To relink: brew unlink libpng && brew link libpng

➜  ~   brew unlink libpng && brew link libpng
    Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.19... 18 symlinks removed
    Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.19... 18 symlinks created
```

And `xz`:

```
brew uninstall xz
brew uninstall imagemagick; brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

And finally go for some harder rebuilding:

```
brew uninstall --force imagemagick; brew install -v imagemagick --build-from-source
```

I looked at the docs for convert's ReadImage:

```
open /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick//6.9.1-10/share/doc/ImageMagick-6/www/api/constitute.html
```

I read the source code for `ReadImage`.

I stop, and look back at the python script.
I **force the script to use jpeg instead of png**.

## It works.

Here is the working history that I attempted:

```
cd /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins
chown jmunsch:admin export-layers-to-pdf.py


cd /var/folders/w1

/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP ~/Desktop/Export_These_Layers.xcf

otool -L /usr/local/bin/convert

brew update && brew upgrade
brew reinstall imagemagick

ls /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
stat /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib

otool -L /usr/local/bin/convert

cp /usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib


locate libpng16
cp /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.18/lib/libpng16.16.dylib /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib

locate liblzma.5.dylib
otool -L /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
otool -L /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
cp /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib

which convert
ls -la /usr/local/bin/convert

ls /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/
ls /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la
stat /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la

convert '/var/folders/w1/gg1rwbxd17x07kv9swxwv84h0000gn/T/tmpsPHsvG.png' '/var/folders/w1/gg1rwbxd17x07kv9swxwv84h0000gn/T/tmpXGKL0S.png' '/var/folders/w1/gg1rwbxd17x07kv9swxwv84h0000gn/T/tmp196lyv.png' '/var/folders/w1/gg1rwbxd17x07kv9swxwv84h0000gn/T/tmprNZdlG.png' '/Users/jmunsch/Desktop/hggfd.pdf'

brew doctor
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

ls /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16
ls /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-6/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders
cd ~/Desktop
python test.py

open /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick//6.9.1-10/share/doc/ImageMagick-6/www/api/constitute.html

brew uninstall imagemagick; brew install imagemagick;brew install libpng; brew link libpng
brew --config
brew uninstall xz
brew uninstall imagemagick; brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
brew uninstall --force imagemagick; brew install -v imagemagick --build-from-source


cp /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib

brew uninstall --force imagemagick

brew update && brew upgrade && brew uninstall --force imagemagick && brew install -v imagemagick --build-from-source
which convert
ls -la /usr/local/bin/convert
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent my afternoon contending with the same issue.

You can fully alleviate the problem by changing the plugin's `combine_images_into_pdf` function:

```
def combine_images_into_pdf(img_files, pdf_file):
  try:    # Run on shell because of conflict with windows system command 'convert.exe'
    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    my_env["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/usr/local/lib:"
    p = subprocess.Popen(['convert'] + img_files + [pdf_file], env=my_env)
    p.wait() 
  except Exception as e:
    pdb.gimp_message("Error while executing 'convert' command:\n" + 
    str(e) + "\n\nHave you installed the ImageMagic package\nand/or\nset the GIMP environment PATH variable?")
```

You will also need to change the imports -- either `import subprocess` or `from subprocess import Popen` instead of `from subprocess import check_call` (in the code block above I used `import subprocess`).

See here for info about Popen:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment

The DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable gets set in the GIMP startup script located at `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP`. The default `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is needed for GIMP to start itself up and compress PNG images (as the errors with `libfreetype`, `libpng`, and `liblzma` show), but you can allow `convert` to use the proper libraries by setting this environment variable to wherever the proper libraries are when you call `Popen`. Since you're using homebrew like me, I assume that using `/usr/local/lib/` for that directory will work.

This way you don't need to delete anything to get the plugin to fully work -- just install all the dependencies and edit the plugin script, and you'll be good to go. The code above doesn't alter GIMP's environment itself, so it won't cause any errors if you go back and edit your images after exporting them.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this very easily by adding the absolute path to the convert executable inside the script.  On my machine it is:

`/opt/local/bin/convert`

This function becomes:

```
def combine_images_into_pdf(img_files, pdf_file):
    try:    # Run on shell because of conflict with windows system command 'convert.exe'
            check_call(['/opt/local/bin/convert'] + img_files + [pdf_file], shell = True if os.name == 'nt' else False)
    except Exception as e:
            pdb.gimp_message("Error while executing 'convert' command:\n" +
                             str(e) +
                             "\n\nHave you installed the ImageMagic package\nand/or\nset the GIMP environment PATH variable?")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Knigodej](https://github.com/majioa/knigodej) is a tool that does exactly what you want:

> Knigodej gem is a tool to make a PDF, and DJVU books from the XCF (GIMP image) source.