# GIMP python-fu export all open images to pdf error

Tags: gimp, python

I can get the current images open using gimp.image_list() but how can I export them to a single pdf? The function pdb.file_pdf_multi_save() does not work. I do not intend to use ImageMagick, not sure if it still works either.

This is not properly answered in this question: [Export multi page pdf with gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63491/export-multi-page-pdf-with-gimp)

```
from gimpfu import *

# 1012982852

def antiquify(image, rndm_pct, rndm_rcount, randomize, seed, horizontal, vertical, low_threshold, high_threshold, spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y, filename):
    pdb.gimp_undo_push_group_start(image)
    for subimage in gimp.image_list():
        opacity = 80.0
        pdb.gimp_context_set_opacity(opacity)
        drawable=subimage.active_layer
        pdb.plug_in_randomize_pick(image,drawable,rndm_pct, rndm_rcount, randomize, seed)
        # pdb.plug_in_spread(subimage,drawable,spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y)
        # pdb.plug_in_spread(subimage,drawable,spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y)
        # pdb.plug_in_gauss_rle2(subimage,drawable,horizontal, vertical)
        opacity = 100.0
        pdb.gimp_context_set_opacity(opacity)
        pdb.gimp_threshold(drawable, low_threshold, high_threshold)
    images = gimp.image_list()
    # num_images, image_ids = pdb.gimp_image_list()
    pdb.file_pdf_save_multi(len(images), images, False, False, False, filename, filename)
    pdb.gimp_undo_push_group_end(image)

register(
    "python-fu-antiquify",
    "Make a LaTeX document antique",
    "",
    "Masum Billal",
    "Masum Billal",
    "2022",
    "Antiquify",
    "",
    [
        # basic parameters are: (UI_ELEMENT, "variable", "label", Default)
        (PF_IMAGE, "image", "takes current image", None),
        (PF_SLIDER, "rndm_pct", "Random Percent for Pick", 10, (0, 100, .5)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "rndm_rcount", "Number of Iteration for Pick", 1, (0, 10, 1)),
        (PF_BOOL, "randomize", "Randomize or not for Pick", True),
        (PF_INT, "seed", "Seed of randomization for Pick", 1),
        (PF_SLIDER, "horizontal", "Horizontal for Gaussian blur", .5, (0, 10, .5)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "vertical", "Vertical for Gaussian blur", .5, (0, 10, .5)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "low_threshold", "Threshold low", 200, (0, 255, 1)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "high_threshold", "Threshold high", 255, (0, 255, 1)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "spread_amount_x", "Horizontal spread", 2, (0, 20, 1)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "spread_amount_y", "Vertical spread", 2, (0, 20, 1)),
        (PF_STRING, "filename", "PDF Filename", None),
    ],
    [],
    antiquify,
    menu="<Image>/Filters/Noise",
)

main()
```

Comment: Better asked on StackExchange, since this is a programming matter. And when you do so, remember that **"doesn't work"** is not helpful: show what you have coded so far, and the results (or error messages).

Comment: @xenoid - StackOverflow for code questions. They'll need to see some code though.

Comment: @BillyKerr hence the "show what you have coded so far" in my comment  :) And who answers questions tagged `gimp` and `python` over there is anybody's guess :)

Comment: @xenoid Maybe even the [gimp-forum](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Forum-Extending-the-GIMP) - for questions about scripting and plugins for gimp. It seems to be fairly active.

Comment: I intentionally left out the code because mine does more than just export to pdf and I wanted to see another approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to find an answer for this here.

https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-GIMP-Python-Fu-Export-all-open-images-to-pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community people can go to the link and check the answer for themselves. And there were back to back discussions which I cannot put here all at the same thread.